# Rotar un ImageView sin animación en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Necesito rotar un `ImageView` a 180 grados de golpe

Ahora uso la siguiente funcion, que define una animación que dure 0 segundos

```
private void rotate(ImageView iv, float degree) {
    final RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, degree,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    rotateAnim.setDuration(0);
    rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    iv.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
}
```

para rotar a 180º `rotate(imagen,180);`

¿Me pregunto si existe una forma más eficiente? sin tener que recurrir al sistema de animación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una forma de rotar la imagen desde el layout sin necesidad de utilizar animaciones. Agregando el atributo rotation, te dejo un ejemplo.

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_ur_arrow"/>
```